# MinIO operator on minikube is not working

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, minio

I'm trying to use the **MinIO operator** on a minikube (1 node) deployed in an EC2 machine.
The operator is deployed correctly and the same is for the tenant creation and it seems all good until I try to make a connection to the created tenant.
In this case I receive a **500** internal server error then I'm unable to create buckets or to use the mc client that MinIO provides.
I tried both with the MinIO console (using a port-forward) and the command line minio command to create the tenant and both worked.

This is what I see with kubectl:

[mc test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFmKj.png)

[kubectl get all -n minio-tenant-aisync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPJCk.png)

[kubectl get all --all-namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8R8t.png)

I am new to Kubernetes and MinIO then I don't know if I am missing something, could you help me please?

Comment: Hi Salvatore welcome to SO. Please don't post textual content as screenshots;
  it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. This question is not about programming, and thus is on-topic over on https://ServerFault.com/ Good luck

Comment: Need to change node affinity (remove from pods) since minikube supports only single node cluster

Comment: It is easy to make it work with kind cluster . Mini line has some affinity issues

Answer (score 1):

The first `mc` command that you are running shows there is something listening on port `9000` of your `localhost`, however you are getting a TLS verification error because MinIO by default is using a certificate issued by the local kubernetes certificate authority, also the returned certificate is not valid for `localhost` domain,  the solution for this is to add the `--insecure` flag to your mc command (and include it in all subsequent commands unless you use a valid certificate), ie:

`./mc alias set minio https://localhost:9000 [accesskey] [secretkey] --insecure`